# Arduino LCD1602. Вывод цифр вместо текста

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Подключаю LCD1602 Без I2C к Arduino Uno
Со схемой нет проблем, всё работает, но я хочу вывести символ + текст. В данный момент получается вывести символ, но вместо текста выводится набор цифр. В чем проблема, подскажите?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
 
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);   

byte customChar[] = {
  B00101,
  B00100,
  B11111,
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B00100,
  B00111
};
 
void setup()
{
 lcd.createChar(0, customChar);
 lcd.begin(16, 2); 
 lcd.write(byte(0));
 lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
 lcd.print('Hello World!');
}
 
void loop()
{

}
```

Вывод:

t° 25633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lcd.print('Hello World!');

В С++ строковые литералы должны заключаться в двойные кавычки: `lcd.print("Hello World!");`

Символ в одинарных кавычках компилятором воспринимается как одиночный символ, что в С++ вообще-то целое число, а не строка. В более поздних версиях С++ добавили возможность указывать не один символ, а несколько, которые вместе вмещаются в Int. У Arduino int — это два байта. Компилятор взял из вашей строки последние 2 байта, и преобразовал в число.

"Hello World!" — массив char[13] = {0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x21, 0x00} (символ 0 добавляется автоматически компилятором)

'Hello World!' — целое число 0x48656C6C6F20576F726C6421, обрезанное до размера int, то есть 0x6421 = 25633.